# which is better for cortex-m3 Asterisk or using OSIP

Tags: voip

I am trying to port a sip server on cortex-m3 ,asterisk has been successfully compiled with arm codesourcery toolchain but its not working on cortex-m3 with uclinux,how to scale down asterisk or should i go for OSIP